# Put components in Azure ml studio on the "bench"?

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

Is it possible to put modified component in Azure ML studio on the "bench" or on hold? My problem is, that I customized a component, but I want to try out my pipeline with and without the component. But if I just put the component out of the pipeline it gives me an error, bcs. it is not connecte. If I delete the component, I have to configure it again when I want to use it. Is there a solution for that problem?

Comment: You can save a modified component as a new version and then use the new version in your pipeline. Save as a new version by version name and description.

Comment: Check out this Doc for more help: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/machine-learning/how-to-create-component-pipelines-ui.md

Answer (score 0):

You can **archive** the components whenever you don't use it.
And when you required you can **restore** it.

[image]

After clicking on archive you need switch on the view archived option, there you will see all archived components and select required component and restore it.

[image]

you also do this using cli command as below.

```
az ml component archive --name <component-name> --resource-group <resource-group> --workspace-name <workspace-name>
```

For restoring,

```
az ml component restore --name <component-name> --resource-group <resource-group> --workspace-name <workspace-name>.
```

You can refer this [Doucmentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ml/component?view=azure-cli-latest#az-ml-component-create) for more information.